# Distributing an enterprise (in-house) iOS app can't be downloaded by some devices

Tags: ios, enterprise

The plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://www.pushyo.com/mylike/MyLike.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.MyLike.CRM</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.6.20150226</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>subtitle</key>
                <string>crm</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>CRM V1.6.20150226</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Most devices can download and install it successfully, but I find my iPhone5(iOS 8.1.3) and an iPad 2(ios 8) can't download it any more.
I've a link on the website:

```
<a id="download_url" href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.pushyo.com/mylike/MyLike.plist">
```

When I click "install" in the alert window, nothing happened on my iPhone5. How to let it be downloaded by all the iPhone and iPad devices?

Comment: Everything looks proper. Does your device show anything at all after you tap on the itms-services link?

Comment: @Dan No. The alert window disappears and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

After click install in the alert, go back to your springboard to see if your iDevice downloads the application or not. I have the same problem with iOS 8.2, it just does not close safari to show installation process but application will be installed after clicking "Install"

Comment: No. No downloading on the springboard.

Comment: Or maybe those devices are under a MDM profile that they cannot install apps?

Comment: What's MDM profile? I don't know. I've never configured it